# (Dask) How to distribute expensive resource needed for computation?

Tags: pandas, dask, python-3.7, dask-distributed

What is the best way to distribute a task across a dataset that uses a relatively expensive-to-create resource or object for the computation.

```
# in pandas
df = pd.read_csv(...)
foo = Foo() # expensive initialization.
result = df.apply(lambda x: foo.do(x))

# in dask?
# is it possible to scatter the foo to the workers?
client.scatter(...
```

I plan on using this with dask_jobqueue with SGECluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = dask.delayed(Foo)()  # create your expensive thing on the workers instead of locally

def do(row, foo):
    return foo.do(row)

df.apply(do, foo=foo)  # include it as an explicit argument, not a closure within a lambda
```

Comment: Is there a way to use it in the framework of client.map(do, df)? Or, is this the same thing?